# RelativeLayout in ExpandableListView not working

Tags: java, android, listview, expandablelistview

I have an custom ExpandableListView Adapter:

```
public class MyExpandableListView extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<? extends List<? extends Map<String, ?>>> mChildData;
private List<? extends Map<String, ?>> mGroupData;

public MyExpandableListView(Context context,List<? extends Map<String, ?>> GroupData,
        List<? extends List<? extends Map<String, ?>>> ChildData){
    this.context = context;
    this.mChildData=ChildData;
    this.mGroupData=GroupData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mChildData.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_list_layout, null);
    }

    TextView childtxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    childtxt.setText((CharSequence) mChildData.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).get("body"));

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mChildData.get(groupPosition).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mGroupData.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mGroupData.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_list_layout, null);
    }

    TextView time = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item1);
    TextView title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item2);

    time.setText((CharSequence) mGroupData.get(groupPosition).get("time"));
    title.setText((CharSequence) mGroupData.get(groupPosition).get("titel"));
    View view2 = (View)convertView.findViewById(R.id.view2);
    view2.bringToFront();
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

}
```

My group_list_layout.xml is following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="#ff000000" />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="row_id"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:width="100dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="col_1"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:width="300dip" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am trying to display a vertical line in front of the "time" of the group element.

But my view (view2) isn't displayed. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `LinearLayout` is positioned **on top** of the `View` element. Instead move the `View` element **after** the `LinearLayout` in the group layout so it will be placed above it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="row_id"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:width="100dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="col_1"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:width="300dip" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="#ff000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also, inflate your layout like this:

```
convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_list_layout, parent, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

As it is a Relative layout adding android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/view2" to the LinearLayout should work.